# Core data solution for read-write separate

Tags: ios, core-data

I am doing something with core data. Since the original sqlite file contains the data in the application. I decide to do the following:

Separate the reading and writing action. Make all the reading from one data source of one sqlite file and make all the writing in another file.

Since there are some rules in the directory in iOS application, I plan to copy all the reading data from bundle to the cache directory and put the writing data in the document directory.

The question is that, is it possible to use the reading file in the bundle resource directly. Which means I don't have to copy it into the cache file and that will save some space for the device.

Or you guys have any other better idea, please tell me.

> I put the write data into the document because the file in it can be backuped by icloud, which could act as a feature in my program.

Comment: Why do you need separate files?  You can just either read or write to an NSManagedObjectContext, and then save whenever you want.

Comment: @Aaron, I want to separate files because the read only file contains all the data needed, which is large in size. And the write file contains the user activities. When put the write file into the document directory, it could be backed up. That is the reason

Answer (score 0):

You ask if what you want to do is a good idea, but first you need to think through some possible pitfalls.

I suppose the file in your bundle was also created with Core Data, and it has a MOM. The new file you write - it probably uses the same MOM. What will you do if you ever need to update the MOM? The file on iCloud will be say version 1, and maybe the users iPhone uses Version 1, but your new version 2 is loaded onto the users iPad. Now what? The ipad should not update the repository as that would make the iPhone fail when it tries to use the data - the ipad has no way of knowing if all other devices have updated or not.

Comment: Hi David. First of all. The two files, read and write data source are from different MOM.

Comment: Sorry, I did not finish the comment but the lesson starts. I get your idea that there may be a gap of versions in different device and I think that is what the icloud means for users. But in my scenario, my concern is more about to remain the user actions. When user delete the application and reinstall again, the user actions could be downloaded and reuse again. So that't the motivation for me to separate the read only data and write data.